# Google API Adsense - Refresh Token

Tags: api, google-api, token, adsense

I want to get estimated earnings with the Adsense API so I used example from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/HEAD/v2/php.

With this example, I used OAuth to get a JSON:

```json
{
"access_token": "ya29.a0AVAXXXXXX",
"expires_in": 3599,
"scope": "https:\\/\\/www.googleapis.com\\/auth\\/adsense.readonly",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"created": 1661430866,
"refresh_token": "ya29.a0AVA9yXXXXX"
}
```

With this access, I can get the report I want but the token doesn't refresh its expiration date despite using the refresh token.

Why?

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

$client->setAuthConfig($CLIENT_SECRET_FILE_LOCATION);
$service = new Google_Service_Adsense($client);

$refresh_token = json_decode(file_get_contents($token_file),true);
$client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
$newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$token = $client->setAccessToken($newToken);

file_put_contents($token_file, json_encode($newToken["refresh_token"]));
```

---

**EDIT**

I change my code with DalmTo suggestion

```php
 // Set up authentication.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        $client->setAuthConfig($CLIENT_SECRET_FILE_LOCATION);

        $service = new Google_Service_Adsense($client);
        $refresh_token = json_decode(file_get_contents($token_file),true);
        $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
        $token = $client->getAccessToken();

        echo "EXPIRE IN ".($token["expires_in"]).PHP_EOL;

           if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                echo "TOKEN EXPIRED".PHP_EOL;
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
                $newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
                file_put_contents($token_file, json_encode($newToken["refresh_token"]));
                echo "NEW TOKEN SAVED".PHP_EOL;
                echo "EXPIRE IN ".($newToken["expires_in"]).PHP_EOL;
            }
```

Sill not work.

Can i force a refresh token by commenting the if condition ?

```php
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
```

I'm also not sure if i'm saving the good part of the new token in my JSON file

Comment: doesn't refresh ever? or does it for a few days then it stops working

Comment: It doesn't refresh ever...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the section of code which actually refreshes it when the access token is expired.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                
            }
```

Comment: ```php $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken()); ``` 
returns 
```array(2) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "invalid_grant"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(34) "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```
So i have not a new token. Script failed

Comment: You need a new refresh token the one you have has expired request authorizaotn from the user again.   Delete the $token_file it should cause your application to request authorization of the user again.

Comment: I understand but i don't want to request authorization of the user again. I want to get revenue with a cron script automatically. I hoped to do it with a token and refresh tokens...

Comment: Yes but if your refresh token is no longer working for some reason you need to request a new one.

Comment: So what i want to do is not possible?
Let's go to plan B... An AdSense reports every day sent to an email and download attachement the zipfile.  Then use a script to treat it...

Comment: I cant tell you if what you want to do is not possible. I don't know what you want to do.  Im just telling you to try to delete your token file and run the app again and see if it works or not.    If it works then the issue you are having in your question has been solved.     The new question will then be why your refresh token expired in the first place.  It is best to take one issue at a time.

Comment: i want to get automatically, every day,  my adsense revenue via a server script.

Comment: defiantly doable.  although i wonder if adsense api supports service accounts it would probably be easer.